# subranges and operator overloading

Tags: delphi, set, operator-overloading

I can declare the following overload to extend the limitations of the set.

```
TMyInteger = record
private
  Data: integer;
public
  class operator In(a: TMyInteger; b: array of integer): boolean;
end;

class operator TMyInteger.In(a: TMyInteger; b: array of integer): boolean;
begin
  Result:= false;
  for i in b do
    if a.data = i then exit(true);
end;
```

This allows the following syntax:

```
if a in [500,600] then ....
```

Is there a way to allow the following syntax?

```
if a in [500..600] then ....     
//or some similar construct?
```

Comment: There is if you are the engineer responsible for the compiler ;)

Comment: I could do a preprocessor.....

Comment: That you could do. Remember to add line breaks every once in a while :)

Comment: The answer to this question is simply "no"

Comment: I guess the best way would be to add a helper for integer that adds a `function TIntegerHelper.between(MinInclusive, MaxInclusive: integer): boolean` That would work with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: `if InRange(a, 500, 600) then` works for me

Comment: For efficiency you would need to distinguish between ranges and sets. Ranges contain every value between their bounds. Sets can be sparse. Testing for a value in range is to comparisons. Testing set membership is more complex. This issue is more about types than operators.

Comment: Just one question.... why?

Comment: In which compilers is this syntax allowed? ISTM that it should only work in Delphi XE8 and Delphi 10. What is wrong with a function like `InRange()`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I think operator overloading works as from XE3.

Comment: But the `[]` syntax for dynamic array constants doesn't.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ahh, didn't realize that. It feels so natural and pascally.

Comment: @J..., just curious if there is a clean and simple construct that might work for this. For now I've resolved to use a `case` statement. That's the cleanest option.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, but you can achieve something similar, like this. It handles ranges in the format ('5, 17-30, 69') etc. Note that I use '-' rather than '..'

Note I have just cut and pasted functions I have used for many years - you could probably do it better for this particular purpose.

```
unit UnitTest2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils;


type
TMyInteger = record
private
  Data: integer;
public
  class operator In(a: TMyInteger; const pVal : string): boolean;
end;

implementation

{ TMyInteger }

type EDSMListError = class(Exception);

function SplitDSMList( var List : string;
                         var First : integer;
                         var Last : integer ) : boolean;
var
  i : integer;
  ProcessingLast : boolean;
begin
  // splits list of form like '1-3,5,9,11-23' and so on
  // Returns TRUE if there has been a split, and false otherwise.
  // Space characters are ignored

  // If the above string were passed, the return values would be
  // List = '5,9,11-23'
  // First = 1
  // Last = 3
  // return = TRUE

  // The next call would return
  // List = '9,11-23'
  // First = 5
  // Last = 5

  Result := FALSE;
  First := 0;
  Last := 0;
  ProcessingLast := FALSE;

  for i := 1 to Length( List ) do
  begin
    case List[i] of
      '0'..'9':
      begin
        if ProcessingLast then
        begin
          Last := Last * 10 + Ord(List[i]) - Ord('0');
          Result := TRUE;
        end
        else
        begin
          First := First * 10 + Ord(List[i]) - Ord('0');
          Last := First;
          Result := TRUE;
        end;
      end;
      '-':
      begin
        ProcessingLast := TRUE;
        Last := 0;
        Result := TRUE;
      end;
      ',':
      begin
        Result := TRUE;
        List := Copy( List, i + 1, Length( List ) - i);
        Exit;
      end;
      ' ':
        // ignore spaces
        ;
      else
        // illegal character
        raise EDSMListError.Create('Illegal character found in list "' + List + '"');
    end;
  end;
  // If we get here we have reached the end of the message, so...
  List := '';
end;
function ValueInDSMList( const List : string; const Val : integer ) : boolean;
var
  iList : string;
  iBegin, iEnd : integer;
begin
  iList := List;
  Result := FALSE;
  while SplitDSMList( iList, iBegin, iEnd ) do
  begin
    // assume sorted!
    if Val < iBegin then
    begin
      exit;
    end
    else if Val <= iEnd then
    begin
      Result := TRUE;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

class operator TMyInteger.In(a: TMyInteger; const pVal: string): boolean;
begin
  Result := ValueInDSMList( pVal, a.Data );
end;

end.
```

You would then use something like

if a in '500-600' then ....

Comment: As @David pointed out I did not make a reference to performance and this construct might actually be really useful if you're parsing. So +1. If you're already parsing it makes for very clean syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As per David's comment: a construct like  `if a in [500..600]` is not possible.

The best <strike>alternative</strike> workaround from a performance point of view (in 32 bit at least) would be:
This also gives a very clean and flexible syntax.

```
case a of 
  500..600: ;//do work 
end;
//or:
if InRange(a, 500,600) then
```

*In 64-bit a complex case statement does not get optimized, so don't use it in a tight loop.*

In x64 the `case` takes a 1 CPU cycle and `InRange` takes 4 CPU cycles<sup>1</sup>.
Ergo the performance difference is negligible.

<sup>1</sup> Using `RDTSCP` to measure the timings; the single cycle is due to out of order optimizations.

Comment: Your answer has a subrange plus an additional value, which was  not stated in the question. As the question was formed, an `InRange()` alternative would be a good competitor. Did you compare the performance between these two alternatives?

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question asked, which looked for an if statement and made no reference to perf.